# Micro- or macro-averaged AUC for highly imbalanced data?

Tags: machine-learning, roc, unbalanced-classes, auc, model-evaluation

I have a classification problem with 3 classes. With random forest classifier I'm getting the following confusion matrix:

[image]

The micro-averaged AUC is 0.76 and the macro-averaged AUC is 0.55.

On the other hand, let us assume we have the following confusion matrix:

[image]

For this case I'm getting a micro-averaged AUC of 0.91 and a macro-averaged AUC of 0.85, i.e. a much smaller differene in AUC than above.

Should I use for these cases micro- or macro-averaging? I have read that for heavily imbalanced classes (like in my case) it is prefarable to use micro-averaging.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to take into account both micro and macro AUC values, especially when dealing with imbalanced classes in your dataset. Macro AUC offers insights into the performance of the model for each individual class, while micro AUC assesses the overall model performance. The choice between these metrics depends on your specific objectives and the context of the problem. To make an informed decision, consider the nature of your dataset and classes. For instance, if the class distribution is imbalanced techniques like SMOTE can help balance the classes and potentially achieve over 90% accuracy. Additionally, don't forget to experiment with hyperparameter tuning to further enhance your results, especially increase the number of epochs.